# PHP - Reducing an independent record stock value by 1

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, stock

I'm currently doing a school project and I'm using dreamweaver along with a backend database using phpMyAdmin.

Now, what i need to do is, when I click the button, it will reduce the stock column value in the "products" table by 1.

However there are different products in the table. Shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLZXQ.png

So lets say, A user is on the game page for "Destiny" and clicks on the Buy now button, how can i make it reduce the stock level by one, but **only** for the Destiny record and **not** for the Fifa 15 column. So Destiny stock becomes 49, but Fifa stays 50. Will i just need to make each button have a different script or?

Currently, I made a button in the page, which links to an action script, but im not sure what sort of code i will be using.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to do it in Ajax or no ?

Comment: Preferably not, Ive never worked with Ajax. Im just trying to do it via an action script through php if possible?

Answer (score 1):

xNeyte is giving you some good advice, but it comes across to me that you - Xrin - are completely new to programming database contents with PHP or similar?

So some step by steps:

MYSQL databases should be connected with one of two types of connection - **PDO** and **MySQLi_** . MySQL databases will also always work using the native MySQL but as xNeyte already mentioned - this is deprecated and ***highly discouraged*** .

So what you have is you pass your information to the PHP page, so your list of games is on *index.php* and your working page that will update the number of games ordered would be *update.php*, in this example.

The Index.php file passes via anchor link and `$_GET` values (although I highly recommend using a php FORM and `$_POST` as a better alternative), to the update.php page, which needs to do the following things (in roughly this order) to work:

*Update.php*

- Load a valid database login connection so that the page can communicate with the database
- Take the values passed from the original page and check that they are valid.
- establish a connection with the database and adjust the values as required.
- establish the update above worked and then give the user some feedback

So, step by step we'll go through these parts:
I am going to be a pain and use MySQLi rather than PDO - xNeyte used PDO syntax in his answer to you and that is fully correct and various better than MySQLi, for the sake of clarity and your knowledge of MySQL native, it may be easier to see/understand what's going on with MySQLi.

### Part 1:

Connection to the database. 
This should be done with Object Orientated - Classes,

```
class database {
    private $dbUser = "";
    private $dbPass = "";  //populate these with your values
    private $dbName = "";
    public $dbLink;
 public function __construct() {    
$this->dbLink = new mysqli("localhost", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);
            }
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        if ( ! $this->dbLink )
        {
            die("Connection Error (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
            mysqli_close($this->dbLink);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->dbLink->set_charset("UTF-8");
        }
        return true;
    } //end __construct
} //end class
```

The whole of the above code block should be in the `database.php` referenced by xNeyte - this is the class that you call to interact with the database.

So using the above code in the `database.php` object, you need to call the database object at the top of your code, and then you need to generate an instance of your class:

```
include "database.php"; ////include file
$dataBase = new database(); ///create new instance of class.
```

*Now* When you write `$dataBase->dbLink` this is a connection to the database. If you do not know your database connection use the details PHPMyAdmin uses, it carries out its tasks in exactly the same way.

Sooo

### Part 2:

That is that your database connection is established - now you need to run the update: First off you need to check that the value given is valid:

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] >0 ){
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
```

This is simple code to check the value passed from the link is a integer number. Never trust user input.

It is also a good idea never to directly plug in `GET` and `POST` values into your SQL statements. Hence I've copied the value across to `$id`

### Part 3:

```
$sql = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET STOCK = STOCK-1 WHERE Product_ID = ? LIMIT 1";
```

The table name is your table name, the `LIMIT 1` simply ensures this only works on one row, so it will not effect too many stocked games.

That above is the SQL but how to make that work in PHP:

first off, the statement needs to be prepared, then once prepared, the value(s) are plugged into the `?` parts (this is MySQLi syntax, PDO has the more useful `:name` syntax).

So:

```
    include "database.php"; ////include file
    $dataBase = new database(); ///create new instance of class.
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] >0 ){
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET STOCK = STOCK-1 WHERE Product_id = ? LIMIT 1";
    $update = $dataBase->dbLink->prepare($sql);
     $update->bind_param("i",$id);
     $update->execute();  
     $counter = $update->affected_rows;
     $update->close();
     //////gap for later work, see below:

    }
else 
    {
print "Sorry nothing to update";
}
```

There's probably quite a lot going on here, first off the `bind_param` method sets the values to plug into the SQL query, replacing the `?` with the value of `$id`. The `i` indicates it is meant to be an ***Integer*** value. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

The `$counter` value simply gets a return of the number of affected rows and then something like this can be inserted:

```
if ($counter > 0 ){
    print "Thank you for your order. Stock has been reduced accordingly.";
}
else {
    print "Sorry we could not stock your order.";
}
```

### Part 4

And finally if you wish you can then just output the print messages or I tend to put the messages into a SESSION, and then redirect the PHP page back.

I hope this has helped a bit. I would highly recommend if you're not used to the database interactions in this way then either use **PDO** or **MySQLi** but do not combine the two, that will cause all sorts of syntax faults. Using MySQLi means that everything you know MySQL can do, is done better with the addition of the letter "*i*" in the function call. It is also very good for referencing the PHP.net Manual which has an excellent clear detailed examples of how to use each PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to set a link on each button with the ID of your game (1 for destiny, 2 for Fifa15).

Then your script which the user will launch by clicking will be :

```
<?php

include('database.php'); // your database connection

if($_GET['id']) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
} else throw new Exception('Invalid parameter');

$statement = myPDO::getInstance->prepare(<<<SQL
    UPDATE TABLE
    SET STOCK = STOCK-1
    WHERE Product_id = :id
SQL
);

$statement->execute(array(":id" => $id));
```

This script will do the job

Comment: This is the error that is coming up at the moment:
http://prntscr.com/6zi2ya

By "The best is to set a link on each button with the ID of your game (1 for destiny, 2 for Fifa15)."

Do you mean http://prntscr.com/6zi3fv

Comment: Use a link with `<a href='script.php?id={$product['idProduct']'>Test</a>`. You will insert an image, button or something else later on

Comment: That solved the first problem, but now im getting a PDO error
http://prntscr.com/6zi5lu

Comment: This is my personnal PDO class, change syntax with your way to manage database (mysqli or PDO)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. How do i determine what my class is or do i even have one? I presume by syntax you mean class?

Comment: No I mean syntax, you have never managed database with php ? You can use PDO (what i am using with a personnal class to make its using easier) or mysqli methods

Comment: No this is my first time managing a database with PHP. Im not using my own classes, im just using mysql methods. I copied your edited code and im getting syntax error on line 9

Also, why doesnt your php tag close?

Comment: php tag closure is optional and i recommend to never close it because if you have for example one break line after it, it will send header because it will be considered like HTML and will causes errors

Comment: If you use mysql methods (which is not recommanded, since it is deprecated, better use PDO or mysqli), change my syntax with mysql methods